# How to create alias that takes a positional argument in Linux bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Lets say I have a bash command with a couple of options and the variable that I am interested in (e.g. filename):

```
my_cmd option1 option2 filename
```

I created an alias:

```
alias my_cmd_12="my_cmd option1 option2"
```

this allows me to remove typing all of the options. However there are some flags coming after the variable I am interested (e.g. filename):

```
my_cmd option1 option2 filename --flag1
```

How do I create an alias that takes all option an flags:

`my_alias filename` is equivalent to

`my_cmd option1 option2 filename --flag1`

Comment: Same topic on cross-network sites:https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3773/85039 , https://askubuntu.com/q/626458/295286 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131670/3701431

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this with alias. Alias works by replacing string with another string. With this alias defined

```
alias my_cmd_12="my_cmd option1 option2"
```

`my_cmd_12 filename --flag1` will expand to

```
my_cmd option1 option2 filename --flag1
```

But you want to invoke `my_alias filename` to get the same result. There is no way to replace `my_alias` with another string so `--flag1` appears *at the end*.

However a function should work:

```
my_function() { my_cmd option1 option2 "$1" --flag1; }
```

Note this is just a minimal solution tailored to your example. In general you can use more positional parameters or `"$@"`, conditional statements etc., according to what exactly you need. Functions are way more flexible than aliases.

More information here: [*In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618)

Comment: For general "get to know bash better" - http://tldp.org -> guides -> look for "Bash", there are at least two that are worth the effort to read.